# Is it ok to eat after midnight after observing the 8 precepts?

Tags: the-buddha, lay-buddhism, monastery, eight-precepts

if I observe the 8 precepts today,fast in the afternoon and eat at 12am the next day, is it considered a sin?

Comment: Real Buddhism is not a set of rules to follow. It's all about seeing the reality of the mind.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's also not a cheat, when one resolves to keep the Uposatha-precepts for one day, good householder. Sadhu. Nevertheless maybe taking the Buddhas further encouragements into consideration: [Sakka Sutta: To the Sakyans (on the Uposatha)](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.046.than_en.html)

(btw. day starts with sun rise, and eating at right time means from sun rise till sun at zenith, lesser a matter of time by clock as this could be differently.)